# Corners are still visible in SwipeView on iOS, Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I still have the corners displayed when I'm using a SwipeView. It doesn't do this under Xamarin.Android, just only in Xamarin.iOs

[image]

There is the code:

```
<SwipeView BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal">

                    ***** Some code for the SwipeItems ****

        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>

    <Frame Margin="20" HeightRequest="65" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue"
           BackgroundColor="CadetBlue" CornerRadius="20">

                    ***** Some code *****
    </Frame>
</SwipeView>
```

Does someone know why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that you have specified a background color to your SwipeView and BackgroundColor is at times treated differently on different platforms

All you need to do is instead of setting it transparent set it to what your background color should be.

```
<SwipeView BackgroundColor="CadetBlue">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's still the same problem, the corner is still white :(

Comment: Try setting your Frame's padding to 0 and see if that works

Comment: Still no difference, corners still white :(

Comment: Sorry, You're right ! It was a bug, I had to delete the app to make it works correctly and reload. I also have to write the SwipeView like this:   ``<SwipeView>`` with no backgroundColor option at all

Comment: Great that it worked out :)